# How to set up unit tests for Backbone web application

Tags: unit-testing, testing, backbone.js, frontend, marionette

I am working on a single-page web application built with Backbone.js, Marionette.js, jQuery, Handlebars and other front-end libraries. The application uses server APIs to interact with its back-end. I am interested in setting up and writing unit tests for the front-end logic that is growing in size and complexity.

What tools do people use in the industry to test the front-end of a web application? How difficult is it to set up and use? Is there a front-end testing framework that can be used with a Backbone.js application?

I know about mock servers and I don't want to test the front-end with those. I would like to test the JavaScript code (client logic) of a Backbone + Marionette app.

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at backbone.marionette test setup on github. and you can join gitter for getting answers on marionette

Comment: *"I know about mock servers and I don't want to test the front-end with those."*
Well this depends on your codebase, for example if a view renders only after a request succeeds, you will have to mock those. Or maybe you could try stubbing the methods on view constructor prototype to alter such behavior

Comment: Ok, I will look into the test setup for backbone.marionette. Is this the right repo? https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/master/test/unit

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "stubbing the methods on view constructor prototype". The view renders after server request succeeds or fails. Typically, on success, the view displays the data returned by the server. On failure, the view displays an error message.